# How can you get the route name/path of groups?

Tags: 8, routes, group

I am new to Drupal 8. I am working on groups module and want to assign different themes to different groups.So i need route name of groups. how to find route name of groups. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    // Use this theme on a certain route.
    return $route_match->getRouteName() == 'i need route name of groups here';


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a *.routing.yml in the group module where you can find the route name, but routes can also be defined dynamically. So better use a tool, for the command line Drupal Console or for UI the devel module:

Install the [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel), visit the page you want to find out the route name for and click on "Current route info". The route name is in the variable `_route`. You find also the route parameters you might need to further narrow down the route.